# as3 componentevent error

Tags: actionscript-3, components

I am building a form in my project. On stage i have asome comboboxes a checkbox, and, a radio button.

When i run the application in real-time i get this one error. 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ComponentEvent.

I am unsure what caused this error because, i have already imported the ComponentEvent.

The code is below. Can you please tell me how to resolve this error. Thank You.

```
 package  {

     public class Flash_Main {



         import fl.motion.MotionEvent;
         import flash.events.Event;
         import flash.text.TextFormat;
         import fl.data.DataProvider;
         import fl.ComponentEvent;

         public function Flash_Main() {
         // Building the components

   var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
   tf.font = "Arial";
   tf.size = 16;
   tf.color = 0x000000;

   var monthA=     

            ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",   "November", "December"];

  monthCB.dataProvider.dp;

  var dataA:Array = [];
  setDatesF(31);
  function setDatesF(n:int):void {

     for (var i:int=1; i<=n; i++) {

        dataA.push(i);

   }

dp=new DataProvider(dataA);

dateCB.dataProvider=dp;

 }

  var yearA:Array = [];
  for (var i:int= 1910; i<2014; i++) {

     yearA.push(i);

  }

  dp = new DataProvider(yearA);

  yearCB.dataProvider=dp;


  monthCB.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,monthF);

   function monthF(e:Event):void {

     var d:Date = new Date(yearCB.selectedLabel,1+monthA.indexOf(monthCB.selectedLabel),0);

     setDatesF(d.date);

  }

  var items:Array = [
 {label:"London", data:"LondonData"}, 
  {label:"Paris", data:"ParisData"}, 
  {label:"New York City", data:"New York CityData"}, 
  {
 ];                    
  aBb.DataProvider = new DataProvider(items);

   aBb.addEventListener(ComponentEvent.ENTER, onAddItem);

  function onAddItem(event:ComponentEvent):void { 
    var newRow:int = 0; 
    if (event.target.text == "Add") { 
        newRow = event.target.length + 1; 
             event.target.addItemAt({label:"" + newRow, data:"Data" + newRow},  
        event.target.length);  
   } 
 }

  aCb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

  aCd.enabled = false;
  aCe.enabled = false;

  function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
      aCd.enabled = event.target.selected;
      aCe.enabled = event.target.selected;
  }
          }

      }

  }
```

Comment: you have a missing `"` in your month list

Answer (score 0):

change

```
import fl.ComponentEvent;
```

to

```
import fl.events.ComponentEvent;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys. I did has you suggested but, unfortunately i am getting the same error. I am scratching my head wondering what to do next. Any thoughts from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Believe you've got your imports in the wrong location:

```
package
{
    import fl.motion.MotionEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import fl.data.DataProvider;
    import fl.events.ComponentEvent;


    public class Flash_Main {
        public function Flash_Main() {
            // Building the components

            var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            tf.font = "Arial";
            tf.size = 16;
            tf.color = 0x000000;

            var monthA:Array=
                ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",   "November", "December"];

            monthCB.dataProvider.dp;

            var dataA:Array = [];
            setDatesF(31);
            function setDatesF(n:int):void {

                for (var i:int=1; i<=n; i++) {

                    dataA.push(i);

                }

                dp=new DataProvider(dataA);

                dateCB.dataProvider=dp;

            }

            var yearA:Array = [];
            for (var i:int= 1910; i<2014; i++) {

                yearA.push(i);

            }

            dp = new DataProvider(yearA);

            yearCB.dataProvider=dp;

            monthCB.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,monthF);

            function monthF(e:Event):void {

                var d:Date = new Date(yearCB.selectedLabel,1+monthA.indexOf(monthCB.selectedLabel),0);

                setDatesF(d.date);

            }

            var items:Array = [
                {label:"London", data:"LondonData"}, 
                {label:"Paris", data:"ParisData"}, 
                {label:"New York City", data:"New York CityData"}, 
                {
            ];                    
            aBb.DataProvider = new DataProvider(items);

            aBb.addEventListener(ComponentEvent.ENTER, onAddItem);

            function onAddItem(event:ComponentEvent):void { 
                var newRow:int = 0; 
                if (event.target.text == "Add") { 
                    newRow = event.target.length + 1; 
                    event.target.addItemAt({label:"" + newRow, data:"Data" + newRow},  
                        event.target.length);  
                } 
            }

            aCb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

            aCd.enabled = false;
            aCe.enabled = false;

            function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
                aCd.enabled = event.target.selected;
                aCe.enabled = event.target.selected;
            }
        }
    }
}
```